# cannot resolve symbol activity android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using android studio one issues occurred there enable to resolve the issues i have included all the libraries.  [image]

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project again.

Comment: i clean the project and rebuild but get the same issues

Comment: Remove all the imports and try to import the content again one by one

Comment: Please check the error showing in Messages Window after building the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove all item on cache................in android studio

go to that folder  follow like that type of path..........

C:\Users\india.AndroidStudio\system\caches

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build -> Clean Project.
After that, do Rebuild project on Build menu.

Comment: i clean the project and rebuild but get the same issues